# Spring MVC Hibernate Eager Load JSTL c:foreach

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm having an issue with repeating rows when displaying a list orders that has a list a items with a one to many association. The orders will repeat for the the number of items in the order, not once for each order.

Here's my code...
controller mapping

```
    // RETURNS A LIST OF ALL ORDERS IN KITCHEN
    @RequestMapping("/orderstatus")
    public String showAddresses(Model model) {
    List<Orders> deliveryKitchen = ordersService.getDeliveryKitchen();
    List<Orders> deliveryOut = ordersService.getDeliveryOut();
    List<Orders> insideKitchen = ordersService.getInsideKitchen();
    List<Orders> insideOut = ordersService.getInsideOut();
    List<Orders> takeoutKitchen = ordersService.getTakeoutKitchen();

    model.addAttribute("deliveryKitchen", deliveryKitchen);
    model.addAttribute("deliveryOut", deliveryOut);
    model.addAttribute("insideKitchen", insideKitchen);
    model.addAttribute("insideOut", insideOut);
    model.addAttribute("takeoutKitchen", takeoutKitchen);

    return "orderstatus";

}
```

part of .jsp

```
<div>
Delivery
<table class="orders">
    <tr>
        <td>Order #</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td>Street</td>
        <td>Items</td>
        <td>Total</td>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach var="deliveryKitchen" items="${deliveryKitchen}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${deliveryKitchen.idorders}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${deliveryKitchen.users.name}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${deliveryKitchen.users.phoneNo}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${deliveryKitchen.addresses.street1}"></c:out>

    <td>
    <c:forEach var="insideItems" items="${deliveryKitchen.orderitem}">

            <c:out value="${insideItems.items.name}"></c:out>

    </c:forEach>    
...


 what the page shows 
Delivery
Order # Name    Phone Number    Street  Items   Total
57  Panikos 9172955593  214-04 33rd ave Healthy Wrap Meatlover's Omlette           18.4 Out for Delivery    Edit
57  Panikos 9172955593  214-04 33rd ave Healthy Wrap Meatlover's Omlette    18.4    Out for Delivery    Edit
59  Jerry   7894578978  2145 fulton Belgian Style Waffle Chicken Salad Two    Eggs Tuna Salad Sandwich Chicken Noodle Baja Chicken Macaroni and Cheese (kids)  Western Omlette  53.4    Out for Delivery    Edit
59  Jerry   7894578978  2145 fulton Belgian Style Waffle Chicken Salad Two Eggs Tuna Salad Sandwich Chicken Noodle Baja Chicken Macaroni and Cheese (kids) Western Omlette  53.4    Out for Delivery    Edit
59  Jerry   7894578978  2145 fulton Belgian Style Waffle Chicken Salad Two Eggs Tuna Salad Sandwich Chicken Noodle Baja Chicken Macaroni and Cheese (kids) Western Omlette  53.4    Out for Delivery    Edit
59  Jerry   7894578978  2145 fulton Belgian Style Waffle Chicken Salad Two Eggs Tuna Salad Sandwich Chicken Noodle Baja Chicken Macaroni and Cheese (kids) Western Omlette  53.4    Out for Delivery    Edit
59  Jerry   7894578978  2145 fulton Belgian Style Waffle Chicken Salad Two Eggs Tuna Salad Sandwich Chicken Noodle Baja Chicken Macaroni and Cheese (kids) Western Omlette  53.4    Out for Delivery    Edit
59  Jerry   7894578978  2145 fulton Belgian Style Waffle Chicken Salad Two Eggs Tuna Salad Sandwich Chicken Noodle Baja Chicken Macaroni and Cheese (kids) Western Omlette  53.4    Out for Delivery    Edit
59  Jerry   7894578978  2145 fulton Belgian Style Waffle Chicken Salad Two Eggs Tuna Salad Sandwich Chicken Noodle Baja Chicken Macaroni and Cheese (kids) Western Omlette  53.4    Out for Delivery    Edit
59  Jerry   7894578978  2145 fulton Belgian Style Waffle Chicken Salad Two Eggs Tuna Salad Sandwich Chicken Noodle Baja Chicken Macaroni and Cheese (kids) Western Omlette  53.4    Out for Delivery    Edit

    // GET ORDERS BY STATUS
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Orders> getDeliveryKitchen() {
    Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(Orders.class);
    crit.createCriteria("status", "c");
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("c.idstatus", 2));

    return crit.list();
}
```

Comment: kindly show the DAO code or at least show how you try to retrieve the Orders w/ LineItems (perhaps HQL or Criteria)

Comment: updated. thanks for having a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(Orders.class);
crit.createCriteria("status", "c");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("c.idstatus", 2));
crit.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```